# Error using UPDATE command in SQL using C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, oledb

I get

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80040E10): Can not value for one or more of the required parameters

error while using the code below. the variable 'orderAASerialAA' is set as autoNumber.
'this.row' is string which converted to `int32`.

```
private void updateRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Projects_2012\\Project_Noam\\Access\\myProject.accdb";
    OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
    string myInsertQuery = (String.Format("UPDATE tblOrderAA SET orderAASreialPro='{0}', orderAAcodon1='{1}' " +
        " WHERE orderAASerialAA='{2}'", serialPro.Text, codon1.Text, this.row));
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(myInsertQuery);
    myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myCommand.Connection.Close();

}
```

Comment: `orderAASreialPro` feels like a typo.

Comment: You **should** use parameters instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message usually signals an incorrectly typed column name.

Also I would suggest that you don't create the queries in this way because of sql injection attacks etc. Use [parameterized queries](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

As you said 'this.row' is string which converted to int32.

```
Replace
WHERE orderAASerialAA='{2}'
With
WHERE orderAASerialAA={2}

'' are used for string type input....
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `serialPro.Text` or `codon1.Text` values contains a '?'. This means that this is a [parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx) that should be replace by a value.

Try the righ way to [work with parameters into a oledb query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx) in order to avoid this behavior or sql injection.